# Ajax fails to find PHP file location

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, iis

I have a simple code in a Javascript file that calls a PHP file using Ajax. At the moment it's a simple call and I don't need to pass any variables.

I'm using IIS and the folders structure is the following:

ROOT > sendMail.php
ROOT > JS > chat.js

The call starts from chat.js and it's the following:

```
function sendEmail(params){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "sendMail.php?q=" + params, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    
}
```

But I receive "404 Not Found". Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is sub status code of 404 in log file? You can check sub status code and compare with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code#4xx---client-error). Another things is you need to make sure the request is right. You can see the full request url in chrome developer mode or IIS log will record what request it got.

Comment: I tested the ajax and it can send post request very well. Maybe it is the problem of path. Does the sendMail.php ROOT and JS are folders?

Comment: Hi @BruceZhang, thank you for your answer. Sorry for this question, where can I verify the sub status? 
Regarding the request, I have tried to create another site in IIS: Into the ROOT folder, I have created an index.html file where there is only the same ajax call to the sendMail.php and it's work correctly. In this case, both files are in the ROOT folder.

Comment: @BruceZhang regarding the second answer, I try to be more clear. Into the ROOT folder there is the sendMail.php. In the same ROOT folder there is the JS folder that contains the chat.js.

The problem is that the site is generated by .net and .dll files, so I can't understand the correct path to call my .php

Comment: I have resolved my problem. There was an issue in the server configuration. Thank you for your help!